# javascript scroll to top automatically unless user starts scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I would like to automatically scroll to the top, but bail out if the user starts scrolling.

What I currently have stops the animation prematurely because the scrolling animation is itself scrolling - so it triggers the "stop scrolling if scrolling happens" action.

```
function stop_scrolling_to_top(){
    // stop animation attached to selector
    $('html, body').stop();
}

// scroll to the top automatically
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0}, 1400, "easeOutQuint", function(){ 
    // callback when animation complete
    do_not_do_when_scrolling(stop_scrolling_to_top);
});

// stop animation if scrolling starts
do_when_scrolling(stop_scrolling_to_top);
```

Is there a way to determine if the scrolling is triggered by a human or js? is there a better way entirely?

Comment: `$(window).scroll(function () { console.log('scroll'); });` does this fire if you scroll programatically?

Comment: @Johan yessir it does

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this will help.

It listens for the mousewheel event + keys that can be used to scroll on the page (page up/down, spacebar, arrowkeys etc):

```
$(document).keyup(function(e){

    if($.inArray(e.which, [33,34,32,38,40]) !== -1)
        console.log('key');
        //potential scroll by key

});

$(document).bind((/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) 
                                 ? 'DOMMouseScroll' 
                                 : 'mousewheel', function(e){

    var evt = window.event || e;   
    evt = evt.originalEvent ? evt.originalEvent : evt;               
    var delta = evt.detail ? evt.detail*(-40) : evt.wheelDelta;

    if(delta > 0) 
        console.log('mousewheel up');
        //scroll up
    else
        console.log('mousewheel down');
        //scroll down  
});
```

And if you notice that 'your' scroll is active, stop it like you did above:

```
if($('html, body').is(':animated'))
    $('html, body').stop();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MQQ3F/1/

Answer (score -1):

why not simply listen to the mousewheel event. If it was fired, the user tried to scroll by himself. Also you could listen for a click event if the user clicks somewhere to stop scrolling...

Comment: There are more ways to scroll than the mousewheel.

Comment: scroll could be triggered by up key, down key, scrooll wheel, mouse click on scoroll bar, or some unusual way - this is why listening for the window.scroll event, rather than things that trigger said event

Comment: Yeah u are right. I am curious for a neat solution to this problem.